# geocoding with Python reverse_geocoder

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have this spreadsheet contains city names in Japan(not 100% correct), coordinates of the cities, the lat and lng are correct. My goal is to verify all the city names in our table with those from geocoder database.

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel('desktop/japan.xlsx') #read in the spreadsheet
df['coord']=list(zip(df.lat,df.long)) # zip the lat and lng to make a new series
df.head() 

for x,y in df['coord']:   # use a for loop to find all the records in reverse_geocoder
coordinates=(x,y)
results=rg.search(coordinates)
print (results)
```

I got some results from Jupyter Notebook, and then there is an error, IndexError: list index out of range. How can I fix it? I googled, did not find any useful solutions. How can I print out all the city names? Thank you a million. here is the link to the spreadsheet. 
[Japan city names and coordinates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FARH17kH4bbs3t7rgr9B1ZRRlbtBkf-Lrdy0PrzMpYQ/edit?usp=sharing)

```
      IndexError  Traceback (most recent call=last)
    <ipython-input-6-2a5e602f55a8> in <module>()
     1 for x,y in df['coord']:
     2     coordinates=(x,y)
 ----> 3     results=rg.search(coordinates)
     4     print (results)

      ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-     packages/reverse_geocoder/__init__.py in search(geo_coords, mode, verbose)
      291 
      292     _rg = RGeocoder(mode=mode, verbose=verbose)
      --> 293     return _rg.query(geo_coords)
      294 
      295 if __name__ == '__main__':

     ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reverse_geocoder/__init__.py in query(self, coordinates)
      126         else:
      127             _, indices = self.tree.pquery(coordinates, k=1)
      --> 128         return [self.locations[index] for index in indices]
       129 
       130     def load(self, stream):

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reverse_geocoder/__init__.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      126         else:
      127             _, indices = self.tree.pquery(coordinates, k=1)
       --> 128         return [self.locations[index] for index in indices]
      129 
      130     def load(self, stream):

     IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have missing Lattitiude and Longitude in your file.

```
df = df.loc[df.lat.notna(), :]
df = df.loc[df.long.notna(), :]
```

Add these two lines before reverse geocoding, this will omit all missing values.

Comment: It worked! I guess I have to drop all the NA's, thank you!!